# T-SQL Selecting Specific Number from Similar Groups

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of numbers:

```
100
101
200
201
300
400
500
501
```

I need a t-sql select query to return the following from the above list:

```
101
201
300
400
501
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you at least explain how are you choosing your results?, I mean, we are just seeing an arbitrary number of rows

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. This list comes from a lookup table that I cannot change.

Comment: Where is this lookup table? The safest way to do it would be to use this lookup table either as the source for the `where` clause of your query, or join to that table on the common field. But beyond that, as others have pointed out, you've provided insufficient information to get a helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

You realize that you've provided almost no information that anyone can use to answer your question, right?  We don't know what the list is: is it a list in a string, a variable, columns in a table, or rows in a table?  Are you trying to see the results in a column, or results in multiple columns?

I'll take a shot at answering anyway.  If you are talking about a list of numbers in a table (`MyTable`) that you need to compare to a list in another table (`MyLookupTable`), then one of these three will work

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyNumber IN 
  (
    SELECT Number
    FROM MyLookupTable 
  )


SELECT *
FROM 
    MyTable 
     INNER JOIN 
    MyLookupTable ON 
        MyTable.MyNumber = MyLookupTable.Number

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyLookupTable 
    WHERE MyLookupTable.Number = MyTable.Number
  )
```